# Xcode view debugger not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, view

Having a strange problem whereby I can't get Xcode's view debugger to work. I'm running Yosemite and Xcode 6.3, iOS 8.3 on the device and when I click view debugger, the app breaks and a white screen shows in Xcode, but no view debugger.

This works fine on my colleagues machine with my device so really am confused.

Any and all ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes you have to pause first and then click the view debugger button. Or even click the view debugger button twice.

Comment: Unfortunately neither this nor the other answer worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to three-finger drag in view debugger where the white screen appears.I have same issue and this solve it